# On click change div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got three images, on click of each, the info for each one should popup inside the wine-info div. How can I do that?

```
<div class="wines">
            <div class="wine">
                <img src="img/wine1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="wine">
                <img src="img/wine2.png">
            </div>
            <div class="wine">
                <img src="img/wine3.png">
            </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wine-info">
 </div>

.wines {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: absolute;
}

.wine {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fovj2okL/

Comment: Where's your js and what info are you referring to in the above codes?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Don't have any js yet.

Answer (score 1):

Give each img an ID and then a corresponding wine-info e.g.

```
<img id=wine1 src="img/wine1.png"/> 
<div id="info-wine1">Foo</div>
```

Then add a click handler that gives the correct info an active class

```
$(".wine").click(function (e) {
     $(".wine-info").removeClass("active");
     var foo = e.target.id;
     $("#info-"+foo).addClass("active");
});
```

in your CSS give .wine-info "display:none;" and .active "display:inline-block;"

And that should do it. enjoy

Comment: I think you need a '#' before info on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

where is the data coming from?
where ever the data is, let's call it `DATA`.

HTML:

```
...
<div class="wine">
  <img src="" onclick="details(1);"/>
</div>
<div class="wine">
  <img src="" onclick="details(2);"/>
</div>
...
<div id="wine-info">
</div>

<script>
function details(wineId)
{
  //DATA = get contents based on wineId 
  document.getElementById("wine-info").innerHTML = DATA;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the img element HTML content when click the "wine" div. So what we can do is just append the img element HTML content to the "wine-info" div as a sub element.

```
<div class="wine">
<img src="img/wine1.png">
</div>
<div class="wine-info">
</div>
<script>
 $(".wine").click(function () {
 $(".wine-info").empty();//empty the div content or you will get two img after second click
 var img=$(this).find("img").html();
 $(".wine-info").append(img);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!